# Custom error page being ignored with Embedded Jetty under RESTeasy domain

Tags: jetty, http-status-code-404, resteasy

This problem is somewhat involved. The short version is that my custom error.html is obeyed sometimes, but not others when using Embedded Jetty/RESTeasy. A small example can be found at https://github.com/pepperdog/sensus (the initial commit).

I have configured the web.xml with a custom error page:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/util/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And this works if you hit a random URL: http://localhost:8080/XYZ

If you hit a RESTeasy URL configured in the web.xml: http://localhost:8080/ListMessages/books this works fine

If you hit a non-existent URL within the RESTeasy domain: http://localhost:8080/ListMessages/books_nonexistent
you only get the standard blank page 404, and not the custom 404. This has not been my past experience using RESTeasy inside a tomcat container, so my assumption is that it is Jetty related. Is this just the way it is, or am I missing something?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but I came across while trying to solve the issue for myself.

If anybody is still looking, the solution is to implement RESTeasy as a Filter instead of a servlet. Per the docs: "The downside of running Resteasy as a Servlet is that you cannot have static resources like .html and .jpeg files in the same path as your JAX-RS services. Resteasy allows you to run as a Filter instead. If a JAX-RS resource is not found under the URL requested, Resteasy will delegate back to the base servlet container to resolve URLs."